# Resize UITableViewCell to show image at maximum size

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I want to show some images and text in a UITableView.

But when I add the image to its UITableViewCell it breaks the layout and overlaps with the next Header.

How can I set the size of the cell containing the image, so that the layout doesn't get broken?

I found some ObjC-Code which suggest this can be done by using heightForRowAtIndexPath, but I couldn't find anything MonoTouch specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [blog post](http://simon.nureality.ca/?p=189).  It is dynamically resizing table cells for text but you can apply this for your images.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

Basically it comes down to inheriting your own UITableViewDelegate and using that for your UITableView so that you get asked for the height of each row via GetHeightForRow.

Comment: I just tried it again and it worked for me. If you are having issues you can alway try the [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Asimon.nureality.ca%2F%3Fp%3D189&oq=cache%3Asimon.nureality.ca%2F%3Fp%3D189&aqs=chrome.0.57j58.14161j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) version.

Answer (score 3):

```
class TableDelegate : UITableViewDelegate {

      public override float GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            // return 50f;
                            //set your cell height;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of your cells are the same height, set the `rowHeight` property of your `UITableView`. Otherwise, use the `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

That's what you do in CocoaTouch/Obj-C. How you convert from native Obj-C into something that will work in MonoTouch, I have no idea. Good luck with that. :-)